Spring Batch upgrade - No Scope registered for scope "Step"
I have a spring batch that does not use spring boot. I am upgrading it to Spring batch version 5
The batch has a reader bean which is stepscopped because I need to access the jobparameters in it.
With Spring batch 5 upgrade, I had to remove the @EnableBatchProcessing annotation and as a result, I am seeing an error :
java.lang.illegalstateexception no scope registered for scope name "step".
I tried registering the StepScope.class into the ApplicationContext as but that didnt solve the problem.
Can you please help me resolve this ? How do we get the StepScope without the EnableBatchProcessing annotation?
Tried registering the StepScope.class in the ApplicationContext

Please add your configuration (what you had and what you now have).

For anyone facing the same problem, the resolution is to manually register the ScopeConfiguration into the context:
context.register(ScopeConfiguration.class)

EnableBatchProcessing brings the ScopeConfiguration in. However now with Spring 5 upgrade, since we remove EnableBatchProcessing, we need to manually register those classes into the context.
